# Probablility of Rolling unfair dice

Tags: probability

Create a table of probabilities for two loaded six-sided dice such that the probability is approximately 0.25 that the sum of the two dice is 7.

Answer (score 1):

Hint(s):

Note that there are numerous solutions. You just need to exhibit one of them.

Consider two fair dice. The proba that the sum of dice is 7 is $6/36=1/6$.

You want to increase that proba to $1/4$, so you need to get of sum of dice equal to $7$ more often. One idea could be to pick one of the favourable outcomes (say, 3+4) and make it more likely by loading the first die so that it makes 3's more often and the second die so that it makes 4's more often.

You just have to write the parameters to reach an equation...